# Get unique elements in two lists where items don't match 100% (just partially)

Tags: c#

My idea is to use a new list (List1) and compare it with another list (List2) and create a new list (List3) that exclude all common elements in both lists and results on the non common elements. The difficult thing (to me) is that List1 and List2 elements are not a true match. List1 elements might be part of List2 elements, but not a truly match. Using exclude does not seem to allow the use of IndexOf to compare the two list elements. 
Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello, how to you create the MyComparer()? for me I need to compare each element in both lists List1 element exists in List2 element (both strings). Can you give me an example?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean from partial match? Is your list a list of strings and partial match is a prefix/suffix match, or a substring match?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have List1 and List2. Below is the simplest way to compare elements in two lists.

```
IList<string> List3 = new List<string>();
foreach (var item1 in List1)
{
   foreach(var item2 in List3)
   { 
     if (item1 == item2)
     {
        List3.Add(item1);
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> My idea is to use a new list (List1) and compare it with another list
> (List2) and create a new list (List3) that exclude all common elements
> in both lists and results on the non common elements.
>
> **From Comments**
>
> I need to compare each element in both lists List1 element exists in
> List2 element (both strings).

One of the easiest ways to find unique from two lists

```
var List1 = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
var List2 = new List<string>() { "a", "e", "f", "g", "c","z" };
var List3 = new List<string>();

List3.AddRange(List1.Except(List2));
List3.AddRange(List2.Except(List1));

List3.ForEach(l=>Console.WriteLine(l));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
List commonElements = new List<string>();

foreach (var smallString in SmallList)
{
   if (large.Any(x => x.Contains(smallString)))
   {
       // Add to common elements
       commonElements.Add(smallString);
   }
}
```

Comment: My List1 strings can be e.g. "Small String" and my List2 elements can be "Big String where Small String can be in". If you compare them like for like there is not a match. "Small String" is different from "Big String where Small String can be in". If you use IndexOf this would work. But the exclude compares the elements in the lists using the Lists itself, and AFAIK you cannot use X=>X... to further filter out what you need. The idea is to use LINQ as far as possible.

Comment: Most likely, peeyush example should work (will need to try it using IndexOf instead of "=") but that uses foreach loops. I don't believe "Exclude" allow this. Any ideas?